# Plot or reshape 2D array matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

i have no idea how can i plot scatter with a 2D array of this type:

```
a=[[x0,t0],[x1,t1],...,[xn,tn]]
```

the plot should be x vs t, maybe instead of doing this with a maplotlib routine be able to reshape a to obtain:

```
a=[[x0,x1,...,xn],[t0,t1,...,tn]]
```

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your data starts in the format a = [[x0, t0]]:

Split x & t into separate lists, then you can pass them into matplotlib.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = [i[0] for i in a]
t = [i[1] for i in a]
plt.plot(x, t)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `numpy.transpose`:

```
import numpy as np
a=[["x0","t0"],["x1","t1"],["xn","tn"]]

np.transpose(a)
# array([['x0', 'x1', 'xn'],
#        ['t0', 't1', 'tn']], 
#       dtype='<U2')
```